# dpkg install of dkms module doesn't fail even though make does

Tags: 18.04, dpkg, dkms

I have a dkms module packaged as a .deb, via `dkms mkdeb foo-mod-dkms/<ver> --source-only`. This is being installed on the target system, as part of a build.

- Looking at `dpkg.log`, it shows that the package has successfully installed.
- `dpkg -l | grep dkms` shows that the package is installed.

However. It's not actually installed.

- If I manually `dpkg purge foo-mod-dkms`, then `dpkg -i foo-mod-dkms`, I can see that the `make` is failing.

Leaving aside the reason that it is failing (it's because `$kernelver` evaluates to the wrong thing when running in the preseed environment, I've hacked `dkms.conf` so that it also fails when I run it manually), I'd like to find out a way to ensure that `dpkg -i` (or `apt-get install`) will actually *fail* when the dkms `make` step fails? I've read the documentation on both `dkms` and `dpkg`, and cannot find any command line flags etc. that I could pass that would ensure that a failure of the dkms `make` will force dpkg to fail.