# Recovering from a failed DKMS module upgrade

Tags: apt, dpkg

I’m running Ubuntu 16.04.6 and I have the [WireGuard PPA](https://launchpad.net/~wireguard/+archive/ubuntu/wireguard) configured so that I can install WireGuard through apt. I tried to upgrade some packages the other day, including WireGuard, but building the module failed. As [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1126986/163358) alludes to, aptitude/dpkg didn’t seem to notice this failure and now reports that WireGuard is up-to-date, while in fact it doesn’t even seem to be usable anymore:

```
$ sudo rmmod wireguard && sudo modprobe wireguard
modprobe: FATAL: Module wireguard not found in directory
  /lib/modules/4.4.0-151-generic
```

How can I revert to some previous (working) version of WireGuard?

### Full transcript of the upgrade

```
$ sudo aptitude upgrade bsdutils git git-man postgresql-client-9.6 \
    postgresql-client-common postgresql-common python2.7 \
    python2.7-minimal python3.5 python3.5-minimal uuid-runtime \
    wireguard wireguard-dkms wireguard-tools
Resolving dependencies...
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bsdutils git git-man libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libpython3.5 libpython3.5-minimal
  libpython3.5-stdlib postgresql-client-9.6 postgresql-client-common postgresql-common python2.7
  python2.7-minimal python3.5 python3.5-minimal uuid-runtime wireguard wireguard-dkms wireguard-tools
19 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 66 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/19.6 MB of archives. After unpacking 1,476 kB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 152374 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bsdutils_1%3a2.27.1-6ubuntu3.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bsdutils (1:2.27.1-6ubuntu3.8) over (1:2.27.1-6ubuntu3.7) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up bsdutils (1:2.27.1-6ubuntu3.8) ...
(Reading database ... 152374 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.5_3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.5:amd64 (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.8) over (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../python3.5_3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.5 (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.8) over (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.5-stdlib_3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.5-stdlib:amd64 (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.8) over (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../python3.5-minimal_3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.5-minimal (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.8) over (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.5-minimal_3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.5-minimal:amd64 (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.8) over (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../uuid-runtime_2.27.1-6ubuntu3.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking uuid-runtime (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.8) over (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.7) ...
Preparing to unpack .../git_1%3a2.23.0-0ppa1~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking git (1:2.23.0-0ppa1~ubuntu16.04.1) over (1:2.22.0-0ppa1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../git-man_1%3a2.23.0-0ppa1~ubuntu16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking git-man (1:2.23.0-0ppa1~ubuntu16.04.1) over (1:2.22.0-0ppa1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../python2.7_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python2.7 (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.8) over (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libpython2.7-stdlib_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.8) over (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../python2.7-minimal_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python2.7-minimal (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.8) over (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libpython2.7-minimal_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython2.7-minimal:amd64 (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.8) over (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql-common_204.pgdg16.04+1_all.deb ...
Leaving 'diversion of /usr/bin/pg_config to /usr/bin/pg_config.libpq-dev by postgresql-common'
Unpacking postgresql-common (204.pgdg16.04+1) over (203.pgdg16.04+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql-client-common_204.pgdg16.04+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking postgresql-client-common (204.pgdg16.04+1) over (203.pgdg16.04+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql-client-9.6_9.6.15-1.pgdg16.04+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking postgresql-client-9.6 (9.6.15-1.pgdg16.04+1) over (9.6.14-1.pgdg16.04+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../wireguard-dkms_0.0.20190905-wg1~xenial_all.deb ...

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  wireguard
Version: 0.0.20190702
Kernel:  4.4.0-151-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

wireguard.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-151-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod....

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 0.0.20190702
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Unpacking wireguard-dkms (0.0.20190905-wg1~xenial) over (0.0.20190702-wg1~xenial) ...
Preparing to unpack .../wireguard-tools_0.0.20190905-wg1~xenial_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking wireguard-tools (0.0.20190905-wg1~xenial) over (0.0.20190702-wg1~xenial) ...
Preparing to unpack .../wireguard_0.0.20190905-wg1~xenial_all.deb ...
Unpacking wireguard (0.0.20190905-wg1~xenial) over (0.0.20190702-wg1~xenial) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19.1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.21) ...
Setting up libpython3.5-minimal:amd64 (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.8) ...
Setting up libpython3.5-stdlib:amd64 (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.8) ...
Setting up libpython3.5:amd64 (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.8) ...
Setting up python3.5-minimal (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.8) ...
Setting up python3.5 (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.8) ...
Setting up uuid-runtime (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.8) ...
Setting up git-man (1:2.23.0-0ppa1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Setting up git (1:2.23.0-0ppa1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Setting up libpython2.7-minimal:amd64 (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.8) ...
Setting up python2.7-minimal (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.8) ...
Setting up libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.8) ...
Setting up python2.7 (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.8) ...
Setting up postgresql-client-common (204.pgdg16.04+1) ...
Setting up postgresql-common (204.pgdg16.04+1) ...
Setting up postgresql-client-9.6 (9.6.15-1.pgdg16.04+1) ...
Setting up wireguard-dkms (0.0.20190905-wg1~xenial) ...
Loading new wireguard-0.0.20190905 DKMS files...
Building only for 4.4.0-151-generic
Building initial module for 4.4.0-151-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.4.0-151-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/0.0.20190905/build/make.log for more information.
Setting up wireguard-tools (0.0.20190905-wg1~xenial) ...
Setting up wireguard (0.0.20190905-wg1~xenial) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11) ...

Current status: 66 (-19) upgradable.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On IRC, the creator of WireGuard suggested that I run

```
apt update && apt upgrade && reboot
```

I did this (using `aptitude update && aptitude full-upgrade` for the first two steps) and it did indeed reenable WireGuard. I’m not really sure *how* it fixed the problem, but one of the things that was upgraded was my kernel, so maybe there was something preventing the WireGuard module from building against the older kernel that was fixed in the newer one.